# Vlc library fails when I use fork() in C and Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, fork, libvlc

I can't understand why I keep to get this error:

```
    ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
[00005617d3cf0630] alsa audio output error: cannot open ALSA device "default": No such file or directory
[00005617d3cf0630] main audio output error: Audio output failed
[00005617d3cf0630] main audio output error: The audio device "default" could not be used:
No such file or directory.
[00005617d3cf0630] main audio output error: module not functional
[00007f2ce803b080] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
```

when I try to reproduce a mp3 file with a fork().

The code works pretty fine if I use it outside the fork().
It looks like the child process can't access the hardware sound card?
I really can't understand how can I solve the problem.

```
pid = fork();
     printf("il pid: %d\n", pid);
     if (pid == 0) {
         libvlc_instance_t *inst;
    libvlc_media_player_t *mp;
    libvlc_media_t *m;

    // load the vlc engine
    inst = libvlc_new(0, NULL);
    printf("apro il file \n");
    // create a new item
    m = libvlc_media_new_path(inst, "/home/robodyne/Downloads/file.mp3");

    // create a media play playing environment
    mp = libvlc_media_player_new_from_media(m);

    // no need to keep the media now
    libvlc_media_release(m);

    // play the media_player
    libvlc_media_player_play(mp);

    sleep(10);

    // stop playing
    libvlc_media_player_stop(mp);

    // free the media_player
    libvlc_media_player_release(mp);

    libvlc_release(inst);

        exit(0);
}
```

**EDIT1: I'm trying to use THREADS**

Following the suggestion of Antti Haapala, I tried to use threads instead of fork() but when I call "pthread_cancel(thread);", the mp3 doesn't stop.

This is my new code:

```
pthread_t thread;

void *wait(void*)
{
    libvlc_instance_t *inst;
    libvlc_media_player_t *mp;
    libvlc_media_t *m;
    // load the vlc engine
    inst = libvlc_new(0, NULL);
    printf("apro il file %d\n", inst);
    // create a new item
    m = libvlc_media_new_path(inst, "/home/robodyne/Downloads/file.mp3");
    // create a media play playing environment
    mp = libvlc_media_player_new_from_media(m);
    // no need to keep the media now
    libvlc_media_release(m);

    // play the media_player
    libvlc_media_player_play(mp);

    sleep(10);
    // stop playing
    libvlc_media_player_stop(mp);
    // free the media_player
    libvlc_media_player_release(mp);
    libvlc_release(inst);


    printf("Done.\n");
}
SecondPage::SecondPage(wxWindow* parent,wxWindowID id)
{
    //(*Initialize(SecondPage)
    Create(parent, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, _T("wxID_ANY"));
    SetClientSize(wxSize(1314,769));
    SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(175,253,202));
    // some code from wxwidgets removed


    m_reboot.Bind(wxEVT_TIMER, &SecondPage::Reboot, this);

     if (get_day_of_year() == 2 || get_day_of_year() == 4){
        secco->Show();
     }

     pthread_create(&thread, NULL, wait, NULL);
}

void SecondPage::OnplasticaClick(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    pthread_cancel(thread);

    thirdpage = new ThirdPage(nullptr, 2);
    thirdpage->selezione="plastica";
    strcpy(thirdpage->codice_fiscale, codice_fiscale);
    thirdpage->tipologia_rifiuto->SetLabel(thirdpage->selezione);
    thirdpage->Refresh();
    thirdpage->Update();
    thirdpage->m_reboot.StartOnce(600000);
    thirdpage->Show(true);
    this->Hide();
}
```

Comment: why have you downvoted my question?

Answer (score 3):

A `fork` is **never** safe in a multi-threaded program, except when immediately followed by `exit` or `exec`. It is not clear what you do *before* calling `fork` but you *do* something non-trivial for sure, otherwise there would not be any difference between this forked version and the one that does not fork.

Unfortunately there are really 3 alternatives:

1. *fork* really early in the program execution, before any libraries are used,
2. *use threads*
3. execute *another* program - for example the same executable with *different arguments so that it knows it is the child* in the forked process.

Comment: I use wxwidgets so the application has a GUI and I need to play mp3 files without blocking the main program flow. Do you think should I use threads? I never did it. I only need to execute a short mp3 file once.

Comment: @MarcusBarnet why did you comment under my answer?

Comment: I did a mistake, sorry. However, I edited my first question because I tried to use threads but when I kill the thread, the mp3 still continue to be reproduced. Why? What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is most likely solved in newer versions like pulseaudio.
Let's define the problem. If you open alsa and then create a fork, allocated resources of alsa shared both by parent and child. This is the big problem for dmix. To avoid this problem, you should either have a separate application where you will do the sound issues, or you should not fork without closing alsa.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).